# Ruby HTTP Library gets Connection Reset with Facebook App

Tags: ruby, facebook, http

The following curl command works as expected:
`curl 'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?grant_type=client_credentials&client_id=myappid&client_secret=myclientsecret'`

I want to do the same thing in my Ruby program.  The following code gives me an error:

```
fb_access_token_url = URI.parse(                                             
    'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token' +                        
    '?grant_type=client_credentials' +                                       
    '&client_id=' + FACEBOOK_APP_ID +                                        
    '&client_secret=' + FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET)                                 
fb_access_token = Net::HTTP.get(fb_access_token_url)
```

So does this code:

```
fb_access_token_host = 'graph.facebook.com'                                  
fb_access_token_path_and_params = (                                          
    '/oauth/access_token' +                                                  
    '?grant_type=client_credentials' +                                       
    '&client_id=' + FACEBOOK_APP_ID +                                        
    '&client_secret=' + FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET)                                 
https_port = Net::HTTP.https_default_port()                                  

fb_access_token = Net::HTTP.get_response(fb_access_token_host,               
                                         fb_access_token_path_and_params,       
                                         https_port)
```

The error is as follows:

```
Errno::ECONNRESET: Connection reset by peer
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:135:in `sysread'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:135:in `rbuf_fill'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:67:in `timeout'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/timeout.rb:101:in `timeout'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:134:in `rbuf_fill'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:116:in `readuntil'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/protocol.rb:126:in `readline'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:2028:in `read_status_line'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:2017:in `read_new'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:1051:in `request'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:948:in `request_get'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:380:in `get_response'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:543:in `start'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:379:in `get_response'
/usr/lib/ruby/1.8/net/http.rb:356:in `get'
./test-login-and-registration.rb:182:in `test_facebook_register'
```

I'm using Ruby 1.8.7 on Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Please look at this question for the answer: 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9336884/getting-a-connection-reset-by-peer-error-when-hitting-google-contacts-api

Comment: When I try that, it can't find the use_ssl= method.  I'm using 1.8.7, not 1.9.3.

Comment: Ohh, I was requiring net/http rather than net/https.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to Manoj Awasthi for making me realize that there were ssl methods that I couldn't use.

The problem was that I was requiring net/http rather than net/https.

Working snippet:

```
fb_access_token_url = URI.parse(                                             
    'https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token' +                        
    '?grant_type=client_credentials' +                                       
    '&client_id=' + FACEBOOK_APP_ID +                                        
    '&client_secret=' + FACEBOOK_APP_SECRET)                                 
https = Net::HTTP.new(fb_access_token_url.host, fb_access_token_url.port)    
https.use_ssl = true                                                         
https.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE                                
fb_access_token = https.request_get(fb_access_token_url.path + '?' +         
                                    fb_access_token_url.query)
```

Comment: don't do this `https.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE ` for anything other than debugging