# Error while using Net::HTTP GET request

Tags: ruby, facebook-graph-api, httprequest

I am new to ruby . I have the following Code snippet which performs a GET operation and retrieves the names of my facebook groups

```
def get_groups
  query=("SELECT gid,name FROM group where gid in(SELECT gid from group_member where uid=me)")
  uri=URI("https://graph.facebook.com/fql")
  params={'q'=>query,'access_token'=>TOKEN}
  uri.query=URI.encode_www_form(params)
  response=Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
  result=json.loads(response.text)
  return result['data']
end
```

But when I execute the above code I get the following errors:

```
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:141:in `read_nonblock': Connection reset by peer (Errno::ECONNRESET)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:141:in `rbuf_fill'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:122:in `readuntil'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/protocol.rb:132:in `readline'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2562:in `read_status_line'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:2551:in `read_new'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1319:in `block in transport_request'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1316:in `catch'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1316:in `transport_request'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1293:in `request'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:1195:in `request_get'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:455:in `block in get_response'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:745:in `start'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/net/http.rb:454:in `get_response'
    from fb.rb:12:in `get_groups'
    from fb.rb:32:in `<main>'
```

What is the mistake that I am making here?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11369234/ruby-http-library-gets-connection-reset-with-facebook-app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the issue here is you're using an HTTP library to access an HTTPS service. These are fundamentally different things. Here's an HTTPS example:

```
require 'net/http'
require 'net/https'
http = Net::HTTP.new('www.example.com', 443)
http.use_ssl = true
http.ssl_version = :TLSv1
http.ciphers = "ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT:!SSLv2:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:-LOW"
http.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_PEER
req = Net::HTTP::Get.new('/', {'Content-Type' =>'application/json'})
http.start {|http| http.request(req) }
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you have SSL certificate validation issue. Try to turn off SSL validation.

```
Net::HTTP.verify_mode = OpenSSL::SSL::VERIFY_NONE
```

If above helps you, possible root of the issue is current OpenSSL installation. Try to update it to the latest version.

Comment: suggesting that someone turn off ssl certificate verification is making the internet an unsafe place.